# iptables - allow forward rules by set

Tags: iptables, nat, forwarding, ipset

I'm building a captive portal (yeah, just-another ;) )
and now I'm trying to handle the core feature, the iptables rules. 
Based on `ipset` I have a list of valid mac-addresses with name `allow-mac`. 
So this is the current config (stripped to the problem itself):

```
echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

ipset create allow-mac hash:mac counters
ipset add allow-mac XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX

IPT="/usr/sbin/iptables"

WAN="eth0"
LAN="eth1"

$IPT -P FORWARD DROP
$IPT -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $WAN -j MASQUERADE
$IPT -I FORWARD -i $LAN -m set --match-set allow-mac src -j ACCEPT
```

This should work but it didn't! so, if I change the default `FORWARD` chain to `ACCEPT` and change the rule to the inverse:

```
$IPT -P FORWARD ACCEPT
$IPT -I FORWARD -i $LAN -m set ! --match-set allow-mac src -j DROP
```

I have the desired result, and only clients with known MAC-address in list can forward.

So my question, why is it not working in the first setup? And my second missing feature is, if the `counters` module is already added, but now the "upload" traffic from client is counted, how can (in a separated counter) I also count the download traffic as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first ruleset, you only allow outgoing traffic as you specified `-i $LAN`: so the reply will be filtered out. It will probably work simply by removing -i $LAN` ?

But in this case the whole traffic will be counted (upload + download)
If you want to count separately upload and download, you'll probably have to create two marking policy:

- one for the upload, where **src** mac is marked
- one for the download, where **dst** mac is marked.